# Would a retiree get the covid19 stimulus payment?

Tags: united-states, irs, covid-19

I have been retired for years, I pay income tax every year on IRA withdrawals and social security income. I don't need the stimulus or think I should get it but my wife ( also retired) is convinced we will get it . Better I should ask here than have a discussion at home. My stock portfolio did take a serious hit.

Comment: As long as you didn't have yearly AGI more than $99k single or $198k joint, and are not a dependent of someone else, yes you are eligible. The income source doesn't matter. Even if you got Social Security (or Railroad Retirement) and _didn't_ pay tax (because for low total income SS/RR is nontaxable) you would qualify. See [top choice on the IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/economic-impact-payment-information-center) especially Q1 and Q2.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Please turn this into an answer

Comment: If you used direct deposit, you should already have gotten it.

Comment: Not as of 4/21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not received your payment yet, you may want to try https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/get-my-payment

Comment: I got it on 4/30 . Getting ready to write checks to my kids , they will get it back into the economy faster.

Comment: @blacksmith37, Congrats!